# Cant get a valid response from post request

Tags: ajax, web-scraping, post, python-requests, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape a website that uses infinite scroll to load the elements.I checked the network tab after inspecting and found out that it is using a POST request with the url `https://search2.raritysniper.com/multi_search?use_cache=true&x-typesense-api-key=L1NoMW9ITm1SYWNodFk4cWpmaHphQWZTS2tuaTVFWDNGdmxjT1llcEpLdz1uNWhMeyJmaWx0ZXJfYnkiOiJwdWJsaXNoZWQ6dHJ1ZSJ9`  .

Now, when i make the same request using the above url in `requests.post(url)`  , the content of the response turn out be **b'{"message": "Bad JSON."}**

Cant figure out what i am doing wrong (Also a newbie to webscrapping ) . So need help!!!!

Comment: I assume that you're missing some payload. Check what data gets sent in the network tab

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but I assumed what you are trying to get is the following, which works for me:

```
import requests

url = 'https://search2.raritysniper.com/multi_search'
params = {'use_cache':True,
          'x-typesense-api-key':'L1NoMW9ITm1SYWNodFk4cWpmaHphQWZTS2tuaTVFWDNGdmxjT1llcEpLdz1uNWhMeyJmaWx0ZXJfYnkiOiJwdWJsaXNoZWQ6dHJ1ZSJ9'
          }
payload = {"searches":
    [
        {"query_by":"name",
         "sort_by":"launchDate:desc",
         "highlight_full_fields":"name",
         "collection":"collections",
         "q":"*",
         "facet_by":"blockchain,supply,sevenDayVolume,floorPrice,totalVolume,thirtyDayVolume,oneDayVolume",
         "max_facet_values":20,
         "page":1,
         "per_page":24
         }
    ]
}
res = requests.post(url, params=params, json=payload)
```

Your problem might have come from the fact you did not properly supplied the payload. I tested using the `data` argument to supply the payload (e.g. `data=payload` instead of `json=payload`), and I got the same error you mentioned. More on that [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Also, I did not really look into the `'x-typesense-api-key'` and the proper way to get it, I just reused there the one I had in my browser but you should probably look out to find a cleaner way to get it.

Note that I used [requests feature](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) to supply the parameters required to the URL, which is a bit cleaner even if it is not required.

Comment: Just like you mentioned, I was actually using 'data=payload' which triggered that issue. Using 'json=payload' solved it...